# Do all Joukowski aerofoils violate no-penetration condition at trailing edge?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics, vector-fields

In our fluids course we calculated the velocity distribution around a completely symmetric Joukowski aerofoil (as shown below) and used the Kutta condition to ensure that the velocity was not infinite at the trailing edge. However, even after applying this condition, the trailing edge had $v_y = 0$ but $v_x \neq 0$ which violates the no-penetration boundary condition.

The lecture notes alluded to this being due to our 'especially symmetric choice of aerofoil', but I can't find online the velocity distributions of aerofoils that aren't symmetric over the x-axis, but I feel like they too may have a 'non-infinite but still violating no-penetration condition' trailing edge.

My question is, is this violation just an artefact of the Joukowski aerofoils all having a *cusp* at the trailing edge? Or is it truly just an artefact of this one particular symmetrical Joukowski aerofoil?

[image]

Comment: The trailing edge "point" of a Joukowski aerofoil is a geometrical point. The "direction of the tangent to the surface" at that point isn't unique. The mathematical notion of "zero velocity normal to the surface" isn't defined at that point.

Comment: So are you agreeing that it is an artefact of the cusp and would occur even for less symmetric joukowski aerofoils which still have cusps?

Comment: Why do you say that $v_y=0$ and $v_x\neq 0$ violates the no-penetration condition? What direction of $\vec v$ at that point would you say does *not* violate the no-penetration condition? (This is just another way of expressing @alephzero's comment.)

Comment: I think that does make sense, so I guess it's less that an artefact of the cusp is that it *breaks* no-penetration condition, and more that an artefact of the cusp is that it can't really break the no-penetration condition because the normal direction is undefined at the cusp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @alephzero and @Chiral Anomaly said, the Joukowski mapping produces a cusp at the trailing edge of the aerofoil which doesnt have a defined normal to the surface, therefore it's less that the no-penetration condition is violated there, but that a direction normal to the surface from which to apply the no-penetration condition doesn't even exist.